# Sed syntax to extract all of text BEFORE last delimiter?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am trying to get the syntax right so that I can make `scanning-client-container-0.2.tar` look like `scanning-client-container`

I am using the delimiter " **-** " like so:

`sed -e 's/-[^*]*$//'`

with the result `scanning`, which is cut off too early

Comment: Where are you using `sed`? If you are piping a single file name from a variable (with something like `echo "$filename" | sed ...`, note that it's much simpler to use the `%` parameter-expansion operator: `filename=${filename%-*}`.

Comment: @chepner, I would add that as an answer (my +1 guaranteed).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis It's not an answer if the OP isn't using `sed` in this way.

Comment: @chepner, it could be an answer for an user ending up on this question while searching for a solution to the use case you describe, no? I mean, the question, as it is at the moment, does not exclude that workflow. However, the choice is yours.

Comment: The question is about `sed`. If it turns out `sed` is being used in a situation where it isn't actually needed, I'll just suggest something more appropriate, but I'm not going to invent an XY problem just to pose something that might be useful to someone in an entirely different context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a negated character class in your regex:

```
sed 's/-[^-]*$//' <<< 'scanning-client-container-0.2.tar'
```

```
scanning-client-container
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `-`: Match a `-`
- `[^-]*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `-`
- `$`: Match end